# T-SQL: Performance of Primary Key with separate Clustered Index and table scans

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, clustered-index

I need help and understanding of why query performance becomes a table scan at a certain point.  Moreover, we need a way to get SQL to not do table scans for relatively simple queries.

Consider the following schema and sample date; note that the primary key is nonclustered with a separate clustered index.

```
create table Mstr (
  Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
  Cluster int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id)
)
create clustered index IE_Cluster on Mstr (Cluster)

create table Detl (
  Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
  Seq int NOT NULL,
  Data varchar(15),
  Cluster int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id, Seq)
)
create clustered index IE_Cluster on Detl (Cluster)
go

ALTER TABLE Detl ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MSTR_DETL FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Mstr
go

insert into Mstr (Id)
select top(1000000) newid()
from sys.all_objects as o1
  cross join sys.all_objects as o2
  cross join sys.all_objects as o3

insert into Detl (Id, Seq, Data)
select Id, 1, 'TEST1' from Mstr union all
select Id, 2, 'TEST2' from Mstr union all
select Id, 3, 'TEST3' from Mstr union all
select Id, 4, 'TEST4' from Mstr union all
select Id, 5, 'TEST5' from Mstr union all
select Id, 6, 'TEST6' from Mstr
```

Transactional performance with this sort of situation is good, especially if we design the clustered index as some sort of strategic hash so SQL is only splitting pages in specific points.

However, if we're trying to do some data-warehouse queries, performance can go to pot pretty quickly.

This query, does Index Seeks and Key Lookups, **GREAT!!**:

```
select count(distinct Data) from Detl 
where [Id] in (select top 2000 [Id] from Mstr)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w80sP.jpg  *(I don't have 10 reputation yet, so can't show the query plan in-line.)*

With this query, it does table scans and bitmaps, **Not so great**:

```
select count(distinct Data) from Detl 
where [Id] in (select top 3000 [Id] from Mstr)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLhtJ.jpg

Comment: I doubt anyone will tell you why sql optimizer chooses scans or seeks.
Did you try to update statistics? Did you try to use FORCESEEK hint?

Comment: An index scan does not equal a table scan. An index scan may be more efficient than an index seek depending on the number of rows being returned in proportion to the rows in the table, [see here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/30/sql-server-index-seek-vs-index-scan-table-scan/).

Comment: Doing index seek **and** key-lookups doesn't have to be all that great...... key-lookups are a very **expensive** operation, so therefore at some point, SQL Server's query optimizer decides that doing an index scan is actually **cheaper** than doing an index seek and a lot of key lookups....

Comment: I think I'm beginning to see that.  Tried with Statistics IO on and some variations of `FORCESEEK` and `MAXDOP 1`.  Maybe an index an index covering the data needed for the read would drop the IO and yield better performance.  In my example, adding `create index IE_Test on Detl (Id, Data)` yields an index seek and immediate result for 3000 rows, and an index scan with no key lookups for 30k rows.  This seems to be a place where a read-only copy of a table would be helpful.